# PHP login.php user not working at mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have a problem to login my user is in the database.
i have the form:

```
<form data-abide method="post" action="confirmar-login.php" id="formlogin" name="formlogin" >
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-8">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="small-3 columns">
                                <label for="email" class="right inline">E-Mail:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="small-9 columns">
                                <input class="radius" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="joao@mail.com" required="">
                                <small class="error">Field required</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-8">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="small-3 columns">
                                <label for="senha" class="right inline">Senha:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="small-9 columns">
                                <input class="radius" type="password" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="****" required="">
                                <small class="error">Field required</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-8">
                        <div class="row">
                            <input type="submit" class="button radius " value="Logar">
                            <a href="cadastro.php" class="button radius " >Cadastrar</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </form>
```

When the login form is submitted it activates confirmar-login.php file And it's the code:
the variable $banco it's where is my database name

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'configuracao.php';
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$conexao -> query("use $banco") or die ("Erro ao selecionar o database");
$result = $conexao -> prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email_usuario = '$email'   and senha = '$senha'") or die("Erro ao selecionar o usuário");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
header('location:index.php');
} else {
unset($_SESSION['email']);
unset($_SESSION['senha']);
header('location:login.php');
}
?>
```

in my file configuracao.php has the code:

```
$conexao = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
```

I am not find the problem ... the query is returning anything and the code is not entering the IF. That is when I put the email and password it just redirects me to the login ...

Comment: You are using PDO so you shouldn't then revert to using `mysql_num_rows`.

Comment: You should see some tutorials on how to use PDO, won't stress that enough because you're using variables inside your prepare.

Comment: mysql_num_rows is just for mysql_connect?
So when i put?

Comment: @Lucas where is the `excecute`? @AndyG i dont think reverting to mysql or mysqli is a good idea..

Comment: @Viscocent I agree, I wasn't suggesting it, I was advising against it.

Comment: Vicocent is true I forgot to run the query. thank you very much

Comment: This is probably worst way evrer i saw for pdo ... and using pdo isnt mean youare safe from sql injection ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using `PDO` so don't use `mysql_*` see the following:

```
$prepared = array(
   'email' => $_POST['email'],
   'senha' = >$_POST['senha']);
$conexao -> query("use $banco") or die ("Erro ao selecionar o database");
$result = $conexao -> prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email_usuario = :email and senha = :senha");

$result->execute($prepared);
if ($result->fetch()) {
```

[official docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: also add the binding for parameters

Comment: The docs confirm that `rowCount` should not be relied upon for SELECT statements.

Comment: @Viscocent - they are in the `$prepared` array?

Comment: a i see, i missed it.

Comment: is more correct if I put: 
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

And

$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email_usuario =:email and senha =:senha";

$result = $conexao -> prepare($sql) or die("Erro ao selecionar o usuário");
$result -> bindParam(':email', $email);
$result -> bindParam(':senha', $senha);
$result->execute();

Or not?

Comment: @LucasAraújo - i only use `bindParam` when i have to, the way i have it written is just as readable and shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You did not run the `->execute()` function of PDO. You can see examples [here](http://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Also, don't mix the [pdo](https://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions and the [mysql](https://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) functions of PHP. They are two different ways of connecting to MySQL. In fact, using the mysql functions is no longer recommended and has been replaced by mysqli and pdo.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email_usuario = ? and senha = ?");
$result->execute(array($email, $senha));

if($result->rowCount() > 0){
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
}
```